# Java HashMap resizing

Tags: java, hashmap

Let's assume we have some code

```
class WrongHashCode{
    public int code=0;

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return code;
    }
}
public class Rehashing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Initial capacity is 2 and load factor 75%
        HashMap<WrongHashCode,String> hashMap=new HashMap<>(2,0.75f);

        WrongHashCode wrongHashCode=new WrongHashCode();
        //put object to be lost
        hashMap.put(wrongHashCode,"Test1");

        //Change hashcode of same Key object
        wrongHashCode.code++;

        //Resizing hashMap involved 'cause load factor barrier
        hashMap.put(wrongHashCode,"Test2");

        //Always 2
        System.out.println("Keys count " + hashMap.keySet().size());
    }
}
```

So, my question is why after resizing hashMap (that, as far, as I understand involves **rehashing keys**), we still have 2 keys in keySet instead of 1 (since key object is same for both existing KV pairs) ?

Comment: where is the actual resizing?

Comment: @ACV, when we add second KV hashMap chunks size became 4 instead of 2 (initial). Or I miss something?

Comment: hashMap.keySet() returns you number of actual keys in hash map. So, as you put two keys, you always get 2.

Comment: have you confirmed via debugging that the HashMap is _actually_ resizing?

Comment: @jtahlborn, yes

Comment: Your code isn't valid. You aren't allowed to modify a key entry after inserting it.

Comment: @EJP, it was done on purpose

Comment: It doesn't matter why you did it. The code isn't valis, so no conclusions can be drawn from how it behaves.

Comment: @EJP, but I still can do what I have done. Yes, may be it's not recommended, but the code is valid, at least because it's executable

Comment: The code is *invalid* because it conflicts with the requirements specified in the documentation for `HashMap`. The compiler isn't obliged to enforce every last piece of Javadoc, and neither is the JVM.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> So, my question is why after resizing hashMap (that, as far, as I understand involves rehashing keys)

It actually does *not* involve rehashing keys – at least not in the `HashMap` code except in certain circumstances (see below).  It involves repositioning them in the map buckets.  Inside of `HashMap` is a `Entry` class which has the following fields:

```
final K key;
V value;
Entry<K,V> next;
int hash;
```

The `hash` field is the stored hashcode for the key that is calculated when the `put(...)` call is made.  This means that if you change the hashcode in your object it will not affect the entry in the HashMap unless you re-put it into the map.  Of course if you change the hashcode for a key you won't be even able to *find* it in the `HashMap` because it has a different hashcode as the stored hash entry.

> we still have 2 keys in keySet instead of 1 (since key object is same for both existing KV pairs) ?

So even though you've changed the hash for the single object, it is in the map with 2 entries with different hash fields in it.

---

All that said, there is code inside of `HashMap` which *may* rehash the keys when a HashMap is resized – see the package protected `HashMap.transfer(...)` method in jdk 7 (at least).  This is why the `hash` field above is not `final`.  It is only used however when `initHashSeedAsNeeded(...)` returns true to use "alternative hashing".  The following sets the threshold of number of entries where the alt-hashing is enabled:

```
-Djdk.map.althashing.threshold=1
```

With this set on the VM, I'm actually able to get the `hashcode()` to be called again when the resizing happens but I'm not able to get the 2nd `put(...)` to be seen as an overwrite.  Part of the problem is that the `HashMap.hash(...)` method is doing an XOR with the internal `hashseed` which is changed when the resizing happens, but *after* the `put(...)` records the new hash code for the incoming entry.

Comment: I see. So, the hash is cached and then it is reused only to find the position of the entry in the new (expanded or contracted depending upon the load factor) hashmap instead of actually rehashing the keys, as taught to most of us in Algorithms etc. classes. Learned something new and important.

Comment: This of course, depends on the implementation of `HashMap`.  I've not looked at (for example) `LinkedHashMap` or other implementations of `Map`.  There's nothing that says that the `Map` implementation can't call `obj.hashcode()` multiple times although, as @jthlborn mentions, it can be expensive to do so.

Comment: That is why it is recommended to use keys that are immutable (or atleast the equals/hashcode part). For the example above, the behavior is implementation defined and can vary for JVM to JVM. It was probably a thought exercise.

Comment: @Gray `HashMap.tranfer`? what version of java is that?

Comment: It's a package method in `HashMap` in jdk 7 @Eugene.

Answer (score 7):

The HashMap actually *caches* the hashCode for each key (as a key's hashCode may be expensive to compute).  So, although you changed the hashCode for an existing key, the Entry to which it is linked in the HashMap still has the old code (and hence gets put in the "wrong" bucket after resize).

You can see this for yourself in the jvm code for [HashMap.resize()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.resize%28%29) (or a little easier to see in the java 6 code [HashMap.transfer()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.transfer%28java.util.HashMap.Entry%5B%5D%29)).

Comment: I can't tell why you've linked the jdk-6 sources, and why not 8 for example? where there is no such method at all

Comment: @Eugene happened to be the first hit on google when i search for the source for HashMap.  looking at java 8, the answer is still correct, although it's a little harder to decipher from the source.

Comment: @Eugene add java 8 link.

Answer (score 5):

I can't tell why two of the answers rely on `HashMap.tranfer` for some example, when that method is not present in java-8 at all. As such I will provide my small input taking java-8 in consideration.

Entries in a `HashMap` are indeed re-hashed, but not in the sense you might think they do. A re-hash is basically re-computing the already provided (by you) of the `Key#hashcode`; there is a method for that:

```
static final int hash(Object key) {
    int h;
    return (key == null) ? 0 : (h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);
}
```

So basically when you compute your hashcode, `HashMap` will basically say - "i don't trust you enough" and it will *re-hash* your hashcode and potentially spread the bits better (it's actually a `XOR` of the first 16 bits and last 16 bits).

On the other hand when `HashMap` is *re-sized* it actually means that number of bins/buckets is doubled in size; and because bins are *always* a power of two - that means that an entry from a current bin will: potential stay in the same bucket *OR* move to a bucket that is at the offset at the current number of bins. You can find a bit of details how this is done [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45404580/hashmap-resize-method-implementation-detail).

So once a re-size happens, there is no extra re-hashing; actually one more bit is taken into consideration and thus an entry might move or stay where it is. And Gray's answer is correct in this sense, that each `Entry` has the `hash` field, that is computed only once - the first time you put that `Entry`.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find it clearly documented, but changing a key value in a way that changes its `hashCode()` typically breaks a `HashMap`.

`HashMap` divides entries amongst b buckets. You can imagine key with hash `h` is assigned to bucket `h%b`.
When it receives a new entry it works out which bucket it belongs to then if an equal key already exists in that bucket. It finally adds it to the bucket removing any matched key.

By changing the hash-code the object `wrongHashCode` will be (typically and here actually) directed to another bucket second time around and its first entry won't be found or removed.

In short, changing the hash of an already inserted key breaks the `HashMap` and what you get after that is unpredictable but may result in (a) not finding a key or (b) find two or more equal keys.

Answer (score 0):

Because HashMap stores the elements in an internal table and incrementing the code does not affect that table:

```
  public V put(K key, V value) {
        if (key == null)
            return putForNullKey(value);
        int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
        int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
        for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
            Object k;
            if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
                V oldValue = e.value;
                e.value = value;
                e.recordAccess(this);
                return oldValue;
            }
        }

        modCount++;
        addEntry(hash, key, value, i);
        return null;
    }
```

And `addEntry`

```
  void addEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex) {
    Entry<K,V> e = table[bucketIndex];
        table[bucketIndex] = new Entry<K,V>(hash, key, value, e);
        if (size++ >= threshold)
            resize(2 * table.length);
    }
```

As you can see `table[bucketIndex] = new Entry (hash, ...)` so although you increment the code, it won't be reflected here.

Try making the field code to be `Integer` and see what happens?

Comment: Yes, but that table is reconstructed after hashMap resizing

Comment: @VladyslavNikolaiev. No it's not. Where does it say it's reconstructed? I can't see that in the code.

Comment: @ACV4, it's resized when elements count is reached to specific value. After that inner table size is doubled (reconstructed)