# Maximum length of linkedlist bucket in a hash set?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable, hashset, hashcode

What is the maximum size of LinkedList in a HashSet and what happens when that max size is reached, if any? If all the n input elements have hash codes that store values in the same node array of the hash map. i.e what happens when due to a specific input , bucket 0 keeps on growing and rest of the buckets are unfilled.Is rehashing done in that case or is there a specific way to avoid this problem?

Comment: In Java <= 7, **Unlimited**. In Java 8+, the linked list will be converted to balanced tree, though even there, it may in effect be an unlimited linked list.

Comment: @Andreas , so how does it get element in O(1) in unlimited linked list?

Comment: it's actually *amortized* `O(1)`, when searching inside a tree you still get `O(logn)`

Comment: It doesn't, not truly. But with adequate hashing function, the probability of hash bucket collision is small enough that the *amortized* complexity can be considered to be _O(1)_. With a very bad hashing function, all objects may end up in the same bucket, and complexity will be _O(n)_. But, with hashing collections, we assume adequate hashing function, and hence _O(1)_, because otherwise we wouldn't use them.

Comment: That's a linked list not `LinkedList`. It's not bad hashing functions that are the real problem but malicious selected keys (or elements for `HashSet`). Only works if all the keys implement `Comparable` appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

The strategy is somehow implementation specific, but in general when a `HashMap` (and `HashSet` is based on that) reaches 64 entries *overall* and 8 entries in a single bucket, it will be transformed to a `Tree`. Until than a `resize` happens, when a bucket is doubled in size, thus an extra bit is taken into consideration of where to place an entry - this is called `rehash` - this is done to try and move entries to different buckets.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52692803/hashmap-rehash-resize-capacity) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47921663/when-and-how-does-hashmap-convert-the-bucket-from-linked-list-to-red-black-trees) for some implementation specifics.

Comment: Can you please help with the source of this. I have to present this topic and it would be great if I have some official source to explain them better.

Comment: @ajinzrathod source code was "my official" one when I was investing this