# Creating an immutable list from an existing list using streams

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, collectors

There is a list of `Person` objects.

`List<Person> persons = generatePersons();`

An unmodifiableList is created with it.

`List<Person> unmodifiableList = Collections.unmodifiableList(persons);`

I understand that `unmodifiableList` doesn't support add/remove/set operations. At the same time it is not immutable since it has a reference to an existing modifiable list `persons` and whenever changes are made to the `persons` list, the changes are reflected in `unmodifiableList` too.

An immutable list is created this way.

`List<Person> immutableList = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(persons));`

This creates an immutable list since a conversion constructor is being used. No add/remove/set ops can be performed on `immutableList` nor any change in the original list `persons` would reflect in `immutableList`. 
Let's make an assumption that `Person` objects are immutable too.

Now, I want to create these two lists using streams.

The first one, I have created using:

`List<Person> unmodifiablePersons = persons.stream()
.collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), Collections::unmodifiableList));`

I am lost at creating equivalent of immutableList through streams.

How can I do that?

**Edit:**

I added a new `Person` object to the original list `persons` and printed the size of `persons` list and `unmodifiablePersons`. Both give me the same size. 
So, changes are being reflected to `unmodifiablePersons`and hence it is not immutable yet. Am I missing something here?

**Edit 2**

Silly. Should have gone through the docs. `unmodifiablePersons` is indeed an immutable list. Also, the new `Person` object was added before the `unmodifiablePersons` was created and hence the above observation. Super silly.

Comment: Your example _is_ an immutable List. In fact, it's the example the docs give: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-

Comment: @Zircon I have updated my question with my observation. Kindly look into it.

Comment: @Sara you are not - that is indeed a *view* of that `List`

Comment: Would recommend going through [this discussion](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2017-November/050059.html) on the JDK mailing list while `copy` methods were implemented along with collectors to collect to set, list and map.

Comment: @Zircon Updated with Edit 2.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well in your first case *someone* has access to `List<Person> unmodifiableList` and can edit it, but when you `collect` no one has access to that `List` generated by `Collectors.toList` - so you are good.

What you are probably missing is that `Collectors::toList` will create a *new* List - which should really be obvious; and you wrap it into an unmodifiable one, thus the result of that is truly unmodifiable.

Also in java-10 there is special collector for that:

```
List<Integer> result = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4)
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());
```

This collector uses `List::of` internally - immutable collections added in java-9, thus for example they don't support nulls.

Comment: I'm disappointed that they didn't remove the mutability ambiguity from `toList()`. There's not much practical difference between an immutable list and a *possibly* immutable list.

Comment: @shmosel you mean from documentation of `Collectors::toList`?

Comment: @shmosel well removing it might mean that they would have to stick to either mutable or immutable, I guess. there were comments from Stuart Marks that they are thinking that `Collectors::toList` will return an immutable List after all in some future

Comment: Right, but that would be pointless now that there's `toUnmodifiableList()`.

Comment: @shmosel right, and now I wonder why not explicitly specify that `toList` *is* modifiable -well, you can't, sine the documentation is *out there* already. reminds me of `Optional::get` and `Optional::orElseThrow` (without argument)

Comment: There's no harm in making documentation more specific.

Comment: @shmosel [of course](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8211831) [there isn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52692803/hashmap-rehash-resize-capacity) - just like they already did; but in my understanding this would be super low priority

Comment: Checking the implementation, this still accumulates to a mutable list, then makes a full copy into an immutable one.  I was hoping to avoid this copy, while still getting an `AbstractImmutableList` that incurs no copying cost when later used with `List.copyOf`.

Answer (score 6):

With Java10+, you could have used an inbuilt capability [`copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection)) for creating an unmodifiable list, like this:

```
List<Person> persons = generatePersons();       
List<Person> unmodifiableList = List.copyOf(persons);
```

Also, the current list that you're creating using [`Collector.collectingAndThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-) is actually *immutable* as mentioned in the documentation as well.