# When HashMap will use TreeSet as a bucket?

Tags: java, java-8

From `HashMap` docs we can read:

> Note that using many keys with the same hashCode() is a sure way to slow down performance of any hash table. To ameliorate impact, when keys are Comparable, this class may use comparison order among keys to help break ties.

I know that if the key implements `Comparable` interface, on many hash collision, the bucket can transform from `List` to `TreeSet`.

Is it possible to set the capacity, or check when it will transform?

Comment: Where did u get the `TreeSet` from? Also you are saying lots of things into one sentence that are kind of wrong

Comment: From implementation notes of `HashMap` -> not really `TreeSet` but `TreeNodes` which are behaves similar to our `TreeSet`.

Comment: `TreeNode` has nothing to do with `TreeSet`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a `List`, but a `LinkedList`

It's not a `TreeSet`, but a perfectly balanced red black tree

It does not *has* `Comparable`, but *implements*

It does nto depend if you are implementing `Comparable` or not - a bucked will still be transformed from a `LinkedList` to a red black tree. `Comparable` just makes it a bit easier to decide if an entry is red or black, that is move to left or right.

When moving to a tree, the decision is taken on both how many entries exist overall and how many entries exist in that particular bucket.

A lot more to read [In my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47921663/when-and-how-does-hashmap-convert-the-bucket-from-linked-list-to-red-black-trees) if you really want.

Choosing the correct capacity is non-trivial as it seems for a `HashMap`, a lot more to read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52692803/hashmap-rehash-resize-capacity)

Comment: A lot more to read in your comments too. :)

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I marked as duplicate also

Answer (score 1):

In openjdk it does so when a bucket is larger than `static final int TREEIFY_THRESHOLD = 8`

> The bin count threshold for using a tree rather than list for a bin.  Bins are converted to trees when adding an element to a bin with at least this many nodes. The value must be greater than 2 and should be at least 8 to mesh with assumptions in tree removal about conversion back to plain bins upon shrinkage.

Also you must exceed `static final int MIN_TREEIFY_CAPACITY = 64`

> The smallest table capacity for which bins may be treeified. (Otherwise the table is resized if too many nodes in a bin.)
>    Should be at least 4 * TREEIFY_THRESHOLD to avoid conflicts between resizing and treeification thresholds.

Source: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java

Might be different for other implementations. You can not modify this (without using reflection).

Also it is not a tree set but a [red-black tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47921663/when-and-how-does-hashmap-convert-the-bucket-from-linked-list-to-red-black-trees)

Comment: wrong - read the link in my answer

Comment: thanks for the clarification.