# IdentityHashCode in HashMap's bucket

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap

In the implementation details of `HashMap`, I can read:

```
When using comparators on insertion, to keep a
 * total ordering (or as close as is required here) across
 * rebalancings, we compare classes and identityHashCodes as
 * tie-breakers.
```

If I have constant `hashCode` and fine `equals` and my class doesn't implement `Comparable` how exactly it will break the ties and how the tree will be constructed?

I mean - bucket will transform to a tree and will use `System.identityHashCode` to break a tie.
Then  I will try to call `containsKey` method with a different instance (which will have the same `hashCode` and `a.equals(b) == true`) it will have different `identityHashCode` so is it possible that tree will be traversed by the wrong node (left instead right) and it will not find a key?

Am I missing something or this is normal behavior?

Comment: If you have two objects `a` and `b` where `a.equals(b)` is true, then what does it matter which one gets returned by a call to `get`?

Comment: I guess that red-black tree will not use equals, but comparing elements.

Comment: @rgettman `get` will return neither, as it returns a *value* whereas `equals` is invoked on *keys*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bucket will use `identityHashCode` during insertion, but lookup uses only hash codes and `compare()` calls (if available). This means it sometimes needs to scan both subtrees of a node.

The lookup logic looks line this

```
do {
  if (... keys are equal or can be compared ...) {
    // Go left, right or return the current node
    ...
  } else if ((q = pr.find(h, k, kc)) != null)
    // Search the right subtree recursively
    return q;
  else
   // Go to the left subtree
   p = pl;
} while (p != null);
```

See http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/jdk10/jdk/file/ffa11326afd5/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l1901 and note that `tieBreakOrder()` (the method responsible for comparing `identityHashCode`s is not invoked anywhere in `find()`.

Comment: How did it know that he NEED to scan both subtrees? It makes no sense for me. Can you explain?

Comment: Well, it knows (because it checks in a series of `if`s) that there is no way to compare the current tree node with the key it is looking for, but they're not equal. So the thing we are looking for could be anywhere. As you've pointed out we can't rely on `identityHashCode` here, so we must search both parts of the tree.

Comment: Exactly. I added an answer explaining why it does use the identity hash code for inserting, despite it doesn't use it for lookup.

Answer (score 11):

The motivation for the identity hash code base tie breaking is explained right before the cited part:

[HashMap.java, line 212](https://zgrepcode.com/java/oracle/jdk-8u181/java/util/hashmap.java#L-212):

> ```
> * When bin lists are treeified, split, or untreeified, we keep 
> * them in the same relative access/traversal order (i.e., field 
> * Node.next) to better preserve locality, and to slightly 
> * simplify handling of splits and traversals that invoke 
> * iterator.remove. When using comparators on insertion, to keep a 
> * total ordering (or as close as is required here) across 
> * rebalancings, we compare classes and identityHashCodes as 
> * tie-breakers.
> ```

So, ordering by identity hash code provides a stable ordering to help implementing splitting and the `Iterator.remove()` operation (which must support continuing the traversal consistently).

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53659668/2711488), it is not used for lookup operations, as you already said in your question, two equal objects may have different identity codes. So for unequal objects having the same hash code and not implementing `Comparable`, there is no way around traversing all of them and probing via `equals`.

Answer (score 2):

No, you are moving entries to left or right indeed based on `System::identityHashCode` but in that bucket there are entries *still* that have the same hashCode (well not the same, only the portion that matters).

So when you search for something it sometimes has to look at both `left` and `right`, there is no way around it, as simple as that.