# Tree-bins : using identityHashCode to order non-Comparables makes the effort useless?

Tags: java, java-8, tree, hashmap

Almost an extension to [IdentityHashCode in HashMap's bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53658426/identityhashcode-in-hashmaps-bucket) :

I understand that tree bins in Java 8 HashMap implementation are touted to reduce the worst case complexity of lookup to O(lg(n)) instead of O(n) , e.g. for large bins. But for non-Comparable classes, they use `identityHashCode` for ordering insertion. Hence, when `find`ing, we need to lookup in both subtrees.

Now looking in both subtrees instantly converts the worst case complexity : O(n) instead of O(lg(n)). So all hard work of converting to trees, and back un-tree-ifying upon `UNTREEIFY_THRESHOLD` is wasted and we get no advantage ?

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2):

For a non-Comparable, the trees behind a bin takes advantage of faster lookup for objects with *different* `hashCode()` values that are mapped to the same bin.

For objects with the *same* `hashCode()` value, there is nothing that can be done, since there is no distinguishing characteristic. The system has to do a full search of all keys with the same `hashCode()` value.

As the linked question says, the identityHashCodes are only used as tie-breakers during insert. It cannot be used during lookup, because lookup with a *different* object (i.e. differing identityHashCodes) with same content, has to locate a match as defined by `hashCode()` and `equals()`.

Comment: When objects are mapped to the same bin and the other preconditions are met, the `HashMap` always uses the binary tree over the hash code (first). Only for objects with the same hash code, it resorts to their `compareTo` method if they are `Comparable`. But the bottom line remains the same, only when the objects have the same hash code and aren’t comparable or `compareTo` returned zero but `equals` returns `false` and they have the same class name, the identity hash code is used.

Comment: @Andreas yes, having different ```hashCode``` is more likely than being in different bins. But worst case scenario, when searching in both subtrees , is O(N), even if you use red-black trees. So worst case remains O(N). Wouldn't it have been far more intuitive if Java 8 created a new TreeBinnedHashMap which only supported Comparables ?

Comment: @Jeeves Why? Tree-Binned is a performance boost that all Hash Maps benefits from, even Hash Maps of non-Comparables, so why should we have one that doesn't get the performance boost? Tree-Binned is a pure internal performance booster than doesn't change the functionality of the Hash Map, it simply boosts performance when hashing algorithm is less than optimal, though not when it is horrendous, since nothing can fix that.

Comment: As a developer, it may be easy, or doable, to make your class Comparable. But the regular HashMap doesn't encourage you to do so, yet documents a performance advantage that does not fix worst case performance. I am not sure if you agree that the WORST case for non-Comparables is still linear : O(N), because you have not stated it so far explicitly, but that is my point.

Comment: @Jeeves Yes, but the worst case only applies when the hash codes are the *same*, so rather than implementing a functionally meaningless `Comparable` (lots of object don't have a *natural order*), perhaps writing a better hash function would be more appropriate.

Comment: Ok, I'll try once more. Security. It is frequently easy to 1. find out the hash function. OR, 2. calling the hash function on trillions of objects at leisure. Both 1 & 2 can help in making a big database of collisions. Using that database, a system can be attacked.

Comment: @Jeeves And how would *taking away* tree-bins for non-Comparables help improve that? You're not making any sense to me. --- I mean, you're suggesting to create a separate `TreeBinnedHashMap`, implying that you'd remove the tree-binning logic from the regular `HashMap`, losing the binary tree performance boost for objects with different hash codes that happen to fall into the same bin. Your suggestion is making the security *worse*, not better.

Comment: @Jeeves which data type do you have in mind which an application might receive from an external source, which is not comparable, but has a publicly documented hash code implementation?

Comment: @Holger why is such a data type required to be in my mind ?

Comment: @Jeeves because you are claiming that such a type exists and even has so much relevance that someone would collect instances of that type in “a big database of collisions” to attack a system. Which would require that system to use such a data type and accept instances of it as external input.

Comment: @Holger, I am really really not claiming this. I used the phrase "find out" , and you are reading "is publicly documented" ? Are you serious?  I used the phrase , using OR in capitals : "calling trillions of times to make a database", and you understand that it is publicly documented ? What kind of thinking is that ? I have always discussed the worst case, and none of the responses here are bothered about the subject ?

Comment: @Jeeves I'm actually entirely baffled about what you're trying to argue. You're suggesting to take away an improvement from `HashMap`, worsening its performance characteristics, and creating another class named `TreeBinnedHashMap` that works exactly like the current `HashMap`. Why? What do you believe you gain by making `HashMap` *less* effecient? --- I believe you mentioned that `TreeBinnedHashMap` should enforce that elements must be `Comparable`, but since nothing is forcing people to use that class instead of `HashMap`, what do you believe you've accomplished by doing this?

Comment: @Jeeves it's funny that you are so much focusing on the *smallest* obstacle. Most servers *are* build with open source software frameworks which allow getting the hashcode algorithms of their types from public sources. You only need to find in these sources an actual type that doesn't implement comparable, is used as key for large hash maps *and* accepted as input from external sources, to prove that your hypothetical scenario is worth wasting so much time. Oh, and don't forget to explain why Java 8's improvement has made the situation worse than it was in the two decades before it.